# Storing a pthread_t in java via jni

Tags: java, casting, java-native-interface, pthreads

I have an application which has both Java and Native (C/C++) code. I need to store a `pthread_t` in the Java side, what would be the Java and JNI types for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to `void*` and store in a Java `long`.

`pthread_t` is typically a pointer to a system-dependent `struct`; it will be 32 bits (Java `int`) on 32-bit systems and 64-bits (Java `long`) on 64-bit systems.